# How to get "Origin" request header in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cors

How do I get the Origin request header from cross-domain AJAX requests in Rails?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can achieve this in the controller by using:

```
request.headers['origin']
```

Note: You will need to make certain changes in certain config files for your application to be able to respond to a CORS request. Hope you've got that covered.

Comment: Yeah I've got CORS covered, I've used [rack-cors](https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors) gem among other things. All I needed was to respond with a dynamic `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like `request.origin` also works directly in recent rails versions. (at least Rails 6)