# HTTP_ORIGIN always returning nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to get the origin of the request cross-site, I found this answer [How to get "Origin" request header in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22812477/how-to-get-origin-request-header-in-rails) which suggest using

```
request.headers['origin']
```

I also tried

```
request.headers['HTTP_ORIGIN']
```

but both seem to return nil

I'm running this on Rails 6 app

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with your code.
To get a header in Rails, just access it inside `request.headers`.

For example, to get User-Agent:

```
request.headers['User-Agent']
```

And since rails 5, we have the HTTP_ version also:

```
request.headers['HTTP_USER_AGENT']
```

The problem with the Origin header is that it does not always appear in request headers from the browser. It's just needed when the browser sending a cross-origin request.

You can try with some other tools like Postman or curl to see the header is really there:

```
curl -H "Origin: http://yourserver.com" http://yourserver.com
```

Comment: I tried this curl request but it doesn't return anything, I'm sending a request from another website to my app, it was working on rails 5 but since I upgraded to rails 6 I don't know why it's not working, I can't get the origin of the request sender

Comment: @medBouzid is there any middleware to handle CORS requests in your app? I heard some issues with rack-cors on rails 6

Comment: no I don't use rack-cors, I set headers myself in a before_action call for the specific route, what I found is that one of my requests is a regular jsonp while others are simple ajax posts with attribute `crossDomain: true`, the jsonp one is what is failing and HTTP_ORINGIN is null, so I replaced that by HTTP_REFERER in that specific action after that it started working, not sure the HTTP_REFERER is a good replacement but it works!

Comment: maybe adding `crossDomain: true` to the ajax request with jsonp dataType can solve this (haven't tried) but I think this is what caused the issue for me